# build android .apk on the server side? what do I need to setup?

Tags: android, air, adobe, apk, server-side

I'm working on a project that requires me to give users the ability to input some data into a webform and when submitting the data, an .apk will be generated based on the given information for them to download.

I have already built the .apk app with AS3, adobe air using FlashDevelop, I am able to build the .apk in my local computer.

I really don't have any idea on where to start? if I want to build this apk using php...?

any ideas?
Thanks.

Comment: This is the question i am looking for .. have you found any solution ! Care to share what worked for you ?

Comment: yes, I was able to package my apps on server back then but that was a long, long time ago and I have postponed that project right now. I don't have my linux codes with me any longer. but I do remember that I actually didn't compile the .as files at all. I just used the adt from Air SDK to package the .apk files and didn't use the android sdk neither.

Comment: Can we use android sdk too ? Is air one free and easy to use ?

Comment: I am certain that you can use android SDK on server. yes. in my project, I was trying to package .apk for Air projects not java. that's why we used #adoneAir and yes, air is free to use :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you own the server then you can follow the instructions here to install the SDK and Ant:

SDK: http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing.html (Step 2 is what you want.)

Ant: http://ant.apache.org/manual/install.html

Then follow the instructions here:
http://www.ehow.com/how_8744401_compile-android-project-windows.html

If you don't own the server then ask the admins to install the SDK and ant for you.

Once you have that installed, you can use whatever php commands are available for executing commands as required by the ehow instructions

This is for a windows based install, but I expect the linux/max based solution to be similar

Comment: thanks for the links. I'm sure it's a big challenge but I have to get it going :)

Comment: your mostly links are not useful ...please could you provide links again ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install android sdk on the server and execute command line build command from your php script.

Comment: yes, I could guess that I have to do something like that, but could you tell me how I on earth I can install the sdk on the server?! :)

Comment: just google it, plenty of info on the net: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=II3iQm0Ofvk